# Replacing blank values with SQL in Sisense

Tags: sql-server

Anyone here familiar with Sisense?

Within Sisense, I am writing a custom SQL query to return True/False based on a range of numerical values.   Several fields are blank, which is causing the `InRange` function not to work, as the range conditions can't be applied to null/blank values.

I am trying to replace nulls with -999 so that the `InRange` function may apply.  I've tried `ISNULL` and `WHEN` statements to no avail.  These approaches should work in SQL but for some reason Sisense is returning errors.  Does anyone know how I would be able to populate this?

Example Table:

```
State   |  Number of Reps
NY             12
NJ             36
CT             NULL
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of a query that's not working

Comment: Sorry, last comment submitted before finishing

Original Query:

Select * ,  InRange(0, State_Reps.Reps, 5) AS "5 Or More Reps)
From State_Reps

This is returning the error
Found 'InRange' but expected '<End of Expression>'

Now the reason that seems to be happening, is because some states have null values in the Reps column.  So I want to replace the nulls.

Thanks!

Comment: You can always edit the post to add more details with correct formatting.